# Syncing Tab and Grid using different Views to the same primary DAC

Tags: acumatica

I have a grid and a tab that use the same primary DAC. I created a second view for the Tab per Acumatica. My issue is that the Tab and grid do not stay in Sync. Added RepaintControls="All" to AutoCallback and the Tab is in Sync, but the Grid no longer allows adding a row because it immediately repaints the Grid. All the other tabs on the screen work without using the Repaint Controls.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it was not working was a Space in the following:
RepaintControlsIDs="gridmatl,gridStep,gridTool,gridOvhd,totalsform, outsideProcessingform"

Removed the space;
RepaintControlsIDs="gridmatl,gridStep,gridTool,gridOvhd,totalsform,outsideProcessingform"

Now the tab works perfectly fine.